# RPAD mysql fucntion

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using the [RPAD](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) **mysql** function as below,

```
SELECT RPAD(CASE
              WHEN pi.value < 0 THEN SUM(- 1 * ROUND(pi.value, 2))
              ELSE SUM(ROUND(pi.value, 2))
             END,
          19,
          ' ') value
FROM Reports pi
```

It is not padding the spaces. I do not have negative values in my data at the moment. I took the length of the positive values and deduced that it is not padding the spaces. What am i missing?

Comment: Your code should not even be running.

Comment: No problem seems with your [code](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=886232976aba7df03d54780a5f6f4e6b) unless DB's sql_mode=only_full_group_by is open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be returning an error, because you have `pi.value` "bare" with no aggregation function.  However, the pad is working.  You can check this out:

```
SELECT RPAD(SUM(ABS(pi.value)), 19, ' ') as value,
       LENGTH(RPAD(SUM(ABS(pi.value)), 19, ' '))
FROM (SELECT 1 as value) pi;
```

[Here](http://SELECT%20RPAD(SUM(ABS(pi.value)),%2019,%20%27%20%27)%20as%20value,%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20LENGTH(RPAD(SUM(ABS(pi.value)),%2019,%20%27%20%27))%20FROM%20(SELECT%201%20as%20value)%20pi) is a db<>fiddle.

What is probably happening is that your interface is removing trailing spaces -- that is somewhat common.